# Which Konkani script is most similar to pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, writing-system, konkani

The Konkani language is one of the official languages of India and is written in **5** different scripts, which are (in alphabetical order) Devanagari, Kannada, Latin, Malayalam, and Persian.

For someone learning Konkani, is it preferable to learn one alphabet over another for the purpose of pronunciation? I assume that at least one of the scripts has letters that better represent the sound of the language and therefore that one would be preferable for a learner to use.

Answer (score 1):

Devanagari is well suited for reading and writing in Konkani.

`Reasons`:

1) Kannada and Malayalam has some extra alphabets(ಳ,ಱ,ೞ ള,റ,chillukal) which is not required for Konkani.

2) Devanagari script is more familiar(either by learning Sanskrit/Hindi in academics).

3) Using Latin script leads to difficulty in reading.

4) Konkani written in Devanagari can be read by more number of people.

Comment: Please expand your answer. WHY is Devanagari more suited than the others?